# clojure lein: How do I include source from another directory in my project?

Tags: clojure, github, dependencies, leiningen

I have a lein project in one directory, and instead of using the .jar that gets downloaded when I run

```
> lein deps
```

I want to use the source from a cloned github repository (It has recent fixes not in the current jar).  What is the canonical way to do this with leiningen?

Here is my project file:

```
(defproject oroboros "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.1"]
                 [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0"]
                 [clojure-source "1.2.1"]
                 [overtone "0.3.0"]
                 [penumbra "0.6.0-SNAPSHOT"]]
  :native-dependencies [[penumbra/lwjgl "2.4.2"]]
  :dev-dependencies [[native-deps "1.0.5"]
                     [swank-clojure "1.4.0-SNAPSHOT"]])
```

I want to use the overtone repo from github, rather than the one from clojars.

https://github.com/overtone/overtone

Is this possible?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use checkout dependencies. From [Leiningen's README](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/1.x/README.md):

> Q: I want to hack two projects in parallel, but it's annoying to
>   switch between them.
>
> A: Use a feature called checkout dependencies. If you create a
>   directory called `checkouts` in your project root and symlink some other
>   project roots into it, Leiningen will allow you to hack on them in
>   parallel. That means changes in the dependency will be visible in the
>   main project without having to go through the whole
>   install/switch-projects/deps/restart-repl cycle. Note that this is not
>   a replacement for listing the project in `:dependencies`; it simply
>   supplements that for tighter change cycles.

Comment: Adding a checkouts dir and linking the repo in did not work.  Is there more I need to do here?  I don't see this feature described elsewhere.

Comment: if you add a link in the checkouts dir, you don't need to specify the dependency in the project.clj file. in contrast with what the docs imply, you should REMOVE the references from the project.clj file, otherwise lein deps will still break.

Comment: Joost is correct, you should remove overtone from the :dependencies in project.clj.

Comment: Hmmm... that seems to find the live.clj file, but still fails for midi?   java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate midi__init.class or midi.clj on classpath:  (live.clj:1)

Comment: Actually Joost is wrong, you need to keep the dependency in project.clj. Checkout dependencies are supplemental to regular dependencies; they do not replace them. Two reasons: 0) they are not transitive and 1) they are opt-in; other people may want to hack on the project without setting up checkouts.

Comment: @technomancy, what if your dependency isn't available anywhere besides checkouts? (no clojars, local maven repo, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Back when I was using lein I simply put symlinks in my project directory to the checked out Overtone source dir.

I use cake for my Overtone hacking these days which has support for adding external projects to the class path. You just need to add the path to  project.classpath in your project's .cake/config file:

```
project.classpath = /Users/sam/Development/improcess/lib/overtone/src:
```